# Nested Webcomponents "ES2015 style", how to import nested component from outer component

Tags: ecmascript-6, web-component, es6-class, custom-element

I try to develop simples webcomponents in ES2015 style. Component `my-action` is nested into component `my-action-bar`.

In the version who is in [Github](https://github.com/olofweb/ActionBarES2015), in my client page (`demo-action-bar.html`), I "import" the two components. I want to only import `my-action-bar`in my html client page but I don't know how to "import" `my-action` into `my-action-bar` component...

Comment: why don't you use HTML Imports ?

Comment: @Supersharp Could you elaborate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **HTML Imports** to load Web Components dependancies:

In *my-action.html*:

```
<script src="my-action.js"></script>
```

In *my-action-bar.html* :

```
<link rel="import" href="my-action.html"> 
<script src="my-action-bar.js></script>
```

In *demo-action-bar.html*:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-action-bar.html">
...
<my-action-bar></my-action-bar>
```

Alternately you can use standard `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`:

In *my-action-bar.js*:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
    xhr.open( 'GET', 'my-action.js' )
    xhr.onload = function ()
    {
        var script = document.createElement( 'script' )
        script.innerHTML = xhr.response
        document.head.appendChild( script )
    }
    xhr.send()
```

Or you can use a third pary module loader like `RequireJS`.

Comment: Mmmhhh, I hope a better solution that does not require to create an html file for each webcomponent (who are js files) !

Comment: For JS-only files you can use XMLHttpRequest (or fetch). Usually web components are HTML + JS + CSS.

Comment: The goal of writing a component in JS was to simplify the transpilation task. Otherwise, I find complicated (for a beginner like me) to extract the JS to make de transpilation...

Comment: You don't necessarily have to extract JS. You can also insert JS in HTML afer transpilation.

Comment: So you write two files, wc.html (with syle and html template) and wc.js (es2015 script). You transpile wc.js and after that you "merge" files together ? Do you know a Github project who is using this method ?

Comment: No sorry I don't use transpiler.

Comment: I allready use `crisper` to split html and javascript in two files, but I don't know how to merge two files. Any idea ?

Comment: You should use gulp or grunt.